# Machine Learning + Python : Drawing Validation curve

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, naivebayes, sklearn-pandas

I want to draw a validation curve for my Naive Bayes estimator like this:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html

I failed to understand what training score is.

Can anybody explain me?

Comment: training scores are the scores on training sets. In the example given in the link, the mean value (which is the accuracy) is computed as cross-validation is applied. The curve shows the mean accuracy on the training data and validation data for different values of gamma.

Comment: @prashanth : I understood that, but I couldn't get how exactly training score is computed. nagrom97 has already resolved my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Training score is the score achieved during training. For example, when you call something like `yourmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)`, in this case, the orange line. Behind the scenes, your model is making predictions on your **x_train** data (your features, e.g. temperature or humidity) against your **y_train** (your labels/outcome, e.g. raining or not raining). **Very roughly**, the training score is calculated based on how many predictions your model got right. For example, your model could have a score of 0.9436.. (roughly 94%) which means your machine learning model outputted a correct decision 94% of the time.  You will often find that during training, a model has the tendency to score higher than it would on a test set. You can see the orange line looks as if it is at 1.0, effectively scoring 100% but the cross validation (test) scores highest score is just under 100% which is a more common sight.

It can be dangerous to assume a score of 1.0 means your model is perfect, which is where **overfitting** comes in to the picure, which at a high level means your model fits too tightly to your training data and will not generalise well to new data. I would recommend looking into [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) for more information, Sci-Kit learns website has great documentation.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Could you plz explain in detail how training score is computed?

Comment: hey @Debbie I have added a bit more detail for you.

Comment: no metrics is specified here to compute the training score just like I can choose any  metrics like accuracy, f1 score anything of my choice to calculate cross validation scores:
yourmodel.fit(x_train, y_train)

Comment: @Debbie I am not sure what you mean. Do you need help computing the training score?

Comment: Yes I need help. What I asked is to compute validation acore, we can explicitly mention some metric. Likewise how to mention the metric to compute training score?

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724468/python-scikit-learnhow-to-plot-the-curves-of-training-score-and-validation-sc