# Python + Scikit-learn:How to plot the curves of training score and validation score against the additive smoothing parameter alpha

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, naivebayes

I am using k-fold cross validation to compute the optimal value of Additive Smoothing parameter alpha. Also, I want to plot the curves of training accuracy  and validation accuracy against the values of alpha. I wrote a code for that:

```
alphas = list(np.arange(0.0001, 1.5000, 0.0001))

#empty lists that stores cv scores and training_scores
cv_scores = []
training_scores = []

#perform k fold cross validation
for alpha in alphas:
    naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=alpha)
    scores = cross_val_score(naive_bayes, x_train_counts, y_train, cv=20, scoring='accuracy')
    scores_training = naive_bayes.fit(x_train_counts, y_train).score(x_train_counts, y_train)

    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())
    training_scores.append(scores_training)

#plot cross-validated score, training score vs alpha 

plt.plot(alphas, cv_scores, 'r')
plt.plot(alphas, training_scores, 'b')
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('score')
```

Is this the correct way to implement this?

Comment: There is a nice example available here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html

Comment: What is the problem you are having? I wanted to provide you with an answer but then when I copy pasted your code, I found missing modules, and no data. That's enough for several people including me to just skip your question and move on to answer other. Therefore, it would be best if you provide a reproducible code. And yes, your code seems perfectly fine

Comment: @Bazingaa : This code executed successfully. What I am concerened about are the concepts which are implemented here. Kindly see my comment against nagrom97's answer.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar : I have checked with that already. plot_learning_curve() function is used there. This function does train and test splits on its own, whereas, for my project I did train and test splits explicitly. So I wanted to bypass that.

Comment: Your model is alpha dependent (`naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=alpha)`) and so will be your `cv_scores` and `training_scores`. Hence the implementation seems fine to me

Comment: @Bazingaa : Please clarify one thing to me:
naive_bayes.fit(x_train_counts, y_train).score(x_train_counts, y_train)
What does this score() function compute exactly? How many times model makes correct prediction on train set or does it return training errors,i.e, how many times model makes wrong prediction on training set?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) in the context of linear regression

Comment: @Bazingaa : Thanks. Finally got my answer here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want to tweak other model hyper parameters it may be easier to use what is called a [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Using this, you can tweak extra hyper parameters in a simpler way and training scores are available for you. See my below implementation.

```
parameters = {'alpha':[0.0001, 1.5000, 0.0001]}
classifier = GridSearchCV(MultinomialNB(), parameters, cv=20)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

print('Mean train set score: {}'.format(clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the Grid Search approach. I'll definitely try with that later. But, 1. Does my code correctly implement all the concepts? 
2. Training score is just how many times my model makes correct prediction on training data, right?
3. Value of k-fold cross validation score for each alpha is calculated w.r.t. metric accuracy. So basically I am drawing, number of correct predictions on training set by model vs alpha and cross validation score w.r.t. accuracy vs alpha, right? Is it fine?

Comment: @Debbie Yes , your code is fine. You are also correct about the k-fold cross validation aspect you also mentioned.